# How to Resize View so That Its Subviews Get Resized Too

Tags: xcode, resize, frame, subview, superview

My window adds a subview (my root ViewController's view).

Such subview is superview of several other subviews.

I have just finished an app, and now I want to add an ad.

Here's some code:

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
viewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,480-48);
viewController.clipToBounds=YES;
Ad *ad=[Ad alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,480-48,320,48)];
```

The above viewController has several subviews, but they won't resize. The above viewController.view was 320,480 originally and was completely filled with subviews, until the last pixel on the bottom. And after I change its height from 480 to 460, the subviews do not resize, so on the bottom of the view (where the ad goes) some subviews aren't visible.

How can I get the subviews to resize so to fit the parent view (viewController.view), when the latter has its height reduced by 20px? (I am aware that they'll be deformed a bit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the autoresizing mask for the subviews:

```
ad.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

See the [UIView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) for more details.

Comment: @Rod Napier I'm not sure you understood... but the ad is not a subview of the viewController.view. It's a sibling actually. Do you still maintain the above?

Comment: @Rod Napier yeah I think the above holds. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This post was almost useful. I eventually combined several internet sources and a few hours of head scratching and playing around to get it to work. I wrote it up on my blog here: http://workingmatt.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/xcode-5-quartz-composer-bug-fix.html

But for convenience here's the important bit...

#### DisplayController.h

```
#import <Quartz/Quartz.h>
@interface DisplayController : NSObject
{
  __strong QCView * qcView;
  QCCompositionParameterView *qcParamsView;
}

@property (unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet NSWindow *displayWindow;
@property (unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet NSWindow *displaySettings;
@property (strong) IBOutlet QCCompositionParamterView *paramsView;
@end
```

and

#### DisplayController.m

```
@synthesize qcView;
@synthesize qcParamsView;

- (void) awakeFromNib
{
  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Luna Vertical2014" ofType:@"qtz"];
  NSView *superView = [self.displayWindow contentView];
  qcView = [[QCView alloc] initWithFrame:superView.frame];
  [superView addSubview:qcView];
  [superView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
  [superView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
  [qcView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable];

  [superView addConstraint:
   [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: qcView
                                attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem: superView
                                attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                               multiplier: 1
                                 constant: 0]];

  [superView addConstraint:
   [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: qcView
                                attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem: superView
                                attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                               multiplier: 1
                                 constant: 0]];
  [superView addConstraint:
   [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: qcView
                                attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem: superView
                                attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                               multiplier: 1
                                 constant: 0]];
  [superView addConstraint:
   [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: qcView
                                attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem: superView
                                attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                               multiplier: 1
                                 constant: 0]];

  [qcView unloadComposition];
  [qcView loadCompositionFromFile:path];
  [qcView setMaxRenderingFrameRate: 30.0];
  [qcView startRendering];

  if(![qcView loadCompositionFromFile:path])
  {
      NSLog(@"QC Composition failed to load");
      [NSApp terminate:nil];
  }
  NSLog(@"QC Composition has been loaded!!!!");
  NSLog(@"inputKeys: %@", qcView.inputKeys);

  //Create a parameters view
    //Note that a new referencing outlet was added from
    //Display Settings window to DisplayController
    //by dragging the round circle on the far left over 
    //to the blue cube in the xib.
    //Check out displaycontroller.h and .m

  NSView *paramsSuperView = [self.displaySettings contentView];
  qcParamsView = [[QCCompositionParameterView alloc] initWithFrame:paramsSuperView.frame];
  [paramsSuperView addSubview:qcParamsView];
  [paramsSuperView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
  [paramsSuperView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
  [qcParamsView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable];
  [qcParamsView setCompositionRenderer:qcView];

    // If you need mouse/keyboard interaction with QC uncomment this line
    //    qcView.eventForwardingMask = NSAnyEventMask;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! I feel like such a noob!